# AUTOCAD: TEXT becomes very small and vertical when placed in title block in layout screen

Tags: text, autocad

I am using AUTOCAD 2014, and trying to set up a simple title block (name and date of drawing etc.). The problem is that when I input the text using MTEXT or DTEXT and press escape to end that command the text then becomes very small and barely noticeable in the title block (figure (A) and (B) below). It is also aligned in the vertical plane. Does anyone know a way round this? The Autodesk forum (AUGI) in Nov. 2013, at : [TEXT SUDDENLY DISAPPEARS?](http://forums.augi.com/showthread.php?152755-TEXT-SUDDENLY-DISAPPEARS), also describes this problem but I didn't find it helpful enough to solve it.

Thanks,

Brendan

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this question belongs in Stack overflow but rather Super User, additionally the reference you provided directs to Revit Architecture forum not AutoCAD 2014.

With that aside, check your WYSIWYG settings during the text editor. You can toggle that, while in the editor, by bringing up the context menu > Editor Settings > Always Display in WYSIWYG. I suspect that your text style is currently configured at a small size and with vertical effect. Check your current STYLE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by:

- using 'context menu' (right click mouse) in the text mode i.e. in DTEXT
- follow 'editor settings' to display 'Always Display in WYSIWYG'
- In the 'home' tab select 'Annotation' and under 'text style' select 'manage text styles'
- Change the 'height' from say 0.13 to 3.0
- Then under 'Annotation' again and in 'dimension style' select 'standard' which deselects 'ISO - 25'

This gives a reasonably sized text that is horizontal as opposed to vertical.